# Copy EXIF Metadata from TIF to JPEG in C# / VB.NET

Tags: .net, jpeg, tiff, exif

I would really appreciate if you could shed light on this problem.
I have 2 images, one was created from TIF file with metadata, the other is an in-memory image that will be saved as jpeg.
Then I use this routine to transfer exif metadata from first image to the second one (that is from the one created from tif file to the in-memory image):

```
For Each _p In image1.PropertyItems
   image2.SetPropertyItem(_p)
Next
```

And this works perfectly fine. All exif items are successfully copied. I confirmed this by using watches in debug mode. The problem comes when you save image2 as jpeg using this:

```
    Dim eps As EncoderParameters = New EncoderParameters(1)
    eps.Param(0) = New EncoderParameter(Encoder.Quality, 85)
    Dim ici As ImageCodecInfo = GetEncoderInfo("image/jpeg")
    image2.Save("C:\1.jpg", ici, eps)
```

Only very few EXIF properties are saved with image2 jpeg file however, namely only camera model and camera maker. However If I save image2 as TIF, all properties from the original tif will be there. Can anyone explain why is that?

Thanks.

Comment: Actually, a further investigation showed that the metadata does get saved even in jpeg, however apparently in a modified format, as it does not appear in image file's properties for example. You can see it's there in jpeg with Hex Editor, but it is not picked up by Windows and image viewers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [Exiv2Sharp](http://www.ohloh.net/projects/exiv2-sharp) - this wrapper around Exiv2 should provide what you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Sounds very interesting. But, I may be very stupid - how do I download it?